# How to perform two inner joins in a queryset in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I have three models.

```
class A(models.Model):
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    status_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    d=models.ForeignKey(D)

class B(models.Model):
    ***other Fileds*****
    c = models.OneToOneField(C)
    ***other fields***

class C(models.Model):
    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=9,unique=True)
```

I want to perform a query where i can get all the c_name.

```
SELECT * FROM A inner join B  on A.b_id=B.id inner join 
C  on B.c_id=C.id where A.d_id=1 and A.status=6
```

can anyone please help how to do. i found a similar question here, but it is too much complex to understand for a newbie like me.
Thnak you so much already for any help.

Comment: All the c_names for what? `C.objects.values('c_name')`? `a.b.c__c_name`? its unclear what you're asking, I'm also pretty sure you've asked this question before..Also the query you've shown doesn't get the `c_name`, it gets all fields from `c`

Comment: i am a fresher,while i was struggling my friend suggested me to post the question here. i made my account 2 hrs before. and this is my first question.I havent asked any questions before on this website.

Comment: Fair enough, This almost exact question got asked either yesterday or the day before which is why I asked.. If you already have the instance of a then my second snippet should also work. Also, please feel free to ask questions like this if you do get stuck! :)

Comment: Thank you so much. And i would try to learn as much as i can so that someday i can answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
C.objects.filter(b__a__status=6, b__a__d=1).values_list('c_name', flat=True).distinct()
```

or this

```
A.objects.filter(status=6, d=1).values_list('b__c__c_name', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: +1.  thnx. That worked. I needed to perform 5 db queries  where i required multiple inner joins. I used your query and did .query to print it. understood so well that i did all those queries within last 30 mins where i was struggling from last 24hrs.once again thank you so much.